# Acceder a un función dentro de otra función C# intermedio

Tags: c#, funciones, permisos, programación-funcional, librería

Disculpa si no me hago entender, estuve buscando información referente, pero no la encuentro supongo porque el nombre técnico no la sé:

```
public void MiFuncionPrincipal(){
    Console.WriteLine("Usted accedió a la función principal");

    void MiFuncionHija(){
        Console.WriteLine("Accedió a la función Hija");

        void MiFuncionHijadeHija(){
             Console.WriteLine("Función hija de hija");
        }
    }
    void MiFuncionHija2(){
        Console.WriteLine("Accedió a la función Hija");
    }
}
```

Yo trato de acceder.

**Opción 1:**

```
MiFuncionPrincipal(); // Se ejecuta con normalidad
```

**Opción 2:**

```
MiFuncionPrincipal.MiFuncionHija(); // C# no reconoce a mi funcion hija
```

Ahora, ¿de donde saqué tan descabellada idea?

pues veo en algunas librerías que se usan así:
**Ejemplos:**

```
RegistryKey.Create.NewKey("nombre"); // Ejemplo
RegistryKey.Delete.Folder("FolderName"); // Ejemplo
```

Answer (score 2):

Primero en C# no existen funciones globales. Toda función es un método de una clase, que tiene un nivel de acceso que puede ser public, protected, private, internal. Al definir un método dentro de otro método, este último sólo es accesible dentro del scope de la función y no puede usarse fuera de esta.
Lo que vez que se llama de la forma A.B.Funcion () es porque A y B son clases donde B es una clase declarada dentro de A.

Answer (score 1):

En C# 7 se añadieron las funciones locales al lenguaje, es decir, esto es válido:

```
public void MiFuncionPrincipal(){
Console.WriteLine("Usted accedió a la función principal");

void MiFuncionHija(){
    Console.WriteLine("Accedió a la función Hija");

    void MiFuncionHijadeHija(){
         Console.WriteLine("Función hija de hija");
    }
}
void MiFuncionHija2(){
    Console.WriteLine("Accedió a la función Hija");
}
}
```

Pero las funciones locales son privadas en la función principal, es decir, `MiFuncionHija` puede acceder a `MiFuncionHijadeHija` pero no se puede acceder a ella como `MiFuncionPrincipal.MiFuncionHija`.

En llamadas de tipo `A.B.C(arg1, arg2)`, `A` es una clase, `B` es una instancia de una clase definida como propiedad en `A` y `C` es una función pública sobre la clase `B`.